# cannot change navbar colour nor override bootstrap.css

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have a navbar on my website.  But the font is blue and the hover...white.

I want the font white and the background purple.  I cannot seem to override the bootstrap.css even though my style.css is below the bootstrap.css.  I've even tried filling in every colour in .nav bar with #000000; to see what would happen and commenting out...no effect!![image]

```
/* general settings */
html {
 min-height:100%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
background-color:#000;

}
body {
  background-color:000;
  font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif; color:#c4c4c4; font-size:16.0px; line-height:1.19em;
  color:#000;
  font-weight:100;
  margin:0px;
 min-height:100%;
  width:100%;
}



* {
    font-family: Verdana;
  }
a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
a img {
  border:none;
}
h1 {
  font-size:3.5em;
  font-weight:100;
  font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif; color:#c4c4c4; font-size:16.0px; line-height:1.19em;
}
p {
  font-size:1.5em;
}
/*input,textarea {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  background-color:#f7f7f7;
  border:none;
  border-radius:3px;
  font-size:1em;
  font-weight:100;
}
*/


/*input:focus,textarea:focus {
  border:none;
  outline:2px solid #7ed7b9;
}*/
.left {
  float:left;
}
.right {
  float:right;
}
/*.btn {
  background-color:#cecece;
  border-radius:10px;
  color:#000000;
  display:block;
  font-size:1.4em;
  font-weight:400;
  margin:30px 30px;
  padding:10px 30px;
  font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif;
}
.btn:hover {
  opacity:0.10;
}*/





















.btn {
        color: #fef4e9;
        border: solid 1px #da7c0c;
        background: #f78d1d;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#faa51a), to(#f47a20));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #faa51a,  #f47a20);
        filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#faa51a', endColorstr='#f47a20');
}
.btn:hover {
        background: #f47c20;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f88e11), to(#f06015));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f88e11,  #f06015);
        filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f88e11', endColorstr='#f06015');
}
.btn:active {
        color: #fcd3a5;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f47a20), to(#faa51a));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f47a20,  #faa51a);
        filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f47a20', endColorstr='#faa51a');
}




.wrap {
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:1420px;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:0 0px;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}
.wrap:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  margin-right:-0.25em;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
/* header section------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 header {
  height:110px;
}
header .wrap {
  height:100%;
}
header .logo {
  margin-top:10px;
 width:300px;
 height: 100px;
}


h7 {
    text-align: right;
color:#cecece
}















header nav {
  float:right;
  margin-top:17px;
}
header nav ul {
  margin:1em 0;
  padding:0;
}
header nav ul li {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin-right:20px;
}
header nav ul li a {
  border-radius:px;
  color:#000000;
  font-size:1.4em;
  font-weight:400;
  padding:10px 27px;
  text-decoration:none;
   background: ##1bbeb7; display: block; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  }

}
header nav ul li a.active {
  background-color: #000000;
  color:#000000;
}
header nav ul li a.active:hover {
  background: #000000;
  color:000000;
}
header nav ul li a:hover,header nav ul li a.activeSmall {
  color:#000000;
   background: #000000;

}

/* other objects */ .projectObj {
  color:#fff;
  display:block;
}
.projectObj .name {
  float:left;
  font-size:4em;
  font-weight:100;
  position:absolute;
  width:42%;
}
/*.projectObj .img {
  float:right;
  margin-bottom:5%;
  margin-top:5%;
  width:30%;
}*/
.paddRow {
  background-color:#dadada;
  color:#818181;
  display:none;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
.paddRow.aboutRow {
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
  color:#FFF !important;
  display:block;
  font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif; font-size:13.0px; line-height:1.25em;


}
.paddRow .head {
  font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif; font-size:16.0px; line-height:1.25em;
  margin:40px 0;
}
.paddRow .close {
  cursor:pointer;
  position:absolute;
  right:50px;
  top:80px;
  width:38px;
}
.about {
  color:#818181;
    font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif; color:#c4c4c4; font-size:16.0px; line-height:1.25em;

}
.about section {
  margin:0 0 10%;
}
.about .head {
  font-size:4em;
  font-weight:100;
  margin:3% 0;
  font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif; color:#5b5b5b; font-size:16.0px; line-height:1.25em;
}
.about .subHead {
  font-size:2.5em;
  font-weight:100;
  margin:0 0 3%;
}
.about .txt {
  width:60%;
  color:#686868;
}
.about .image {
  width:30%;
}
.about .flLeft {
  float:left;
}
.about .flRight {
  float:right;
}

.image {
  text-align:center;
}
.image img {
  vertical-align:top;
  width:100%;
}

.input {
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:1% 0;
  padding:12px 14px;
  width:47%;
}



button {
  border:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
/*.textarea {
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:200px;
  margin:1% 0;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:12px 14px;
  resize:none;
  width:100%;
}*/
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color:#a7a7a7;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  color:#a7a7a7;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* FF18+ */
  color:#a7a7a7;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color:#a7a7a7;
}
.loader {
  -moz-animation:loader_rot 1.3s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:loader_rot 1.3s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:loader_rot 1.3s linear infinite;
  animation:loader_rot 1.3s linear infinite;
  height:80px;
  width:80px;
}
@-moz-keyframes loader_rot {
  from {
    -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loader_rot {
  from {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes loader_rot {
  from {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.view-enter,.view-leave {
  -moz-transition:all .5s;
  -o-transition:all .5s;
  -webkit-transition:all .5s;
  transition:all .5s;
}
.view-enter {
  left:20px;
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
.view-enter.view-enter-active {
  left:0;
  opacity:1;
}
.view-leave {
  left:0;
  opacity:1;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
.view-leave.view-leave-active {
  left:-20px;
  opacity:0;
}
/* responsive rules */ @media (max-width: 1200px) {
    body {
      font-size:90%;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size:4.3em;
    }
    p {
      font-size:1.3em;
    }
    header {
      height:80px;
    }
    header .logo {
      margin-top:12px;
      width:200px;
    }
    header nav {
      margin-top:11px;
    }
    header nav ul li {
      margin-right:12px;
    }
    header nav ul li a {
      border-radius:23px;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      padding:10px 12px;
    }
    .wrap {
      padding:0 30px;
    }
    .paddRow .close {
      right:30px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .contactForm {
      width:100%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
      font-size:80%;
      margin:0;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size:5em;
          font-color:
    }
    header {
      height:70px;
    }
    header .logo {
      margin-top:20px;
      width:70px;
    }
    header nav {
      margin-top:8px;
    }
    header nav ul li {
      margin-right:5px;
    }
    header nav ul li a {
      border-radius:20px;
      font-size:1.1em;
      padding:8px;
    }
    .wrap {
      padding:0 15px;
    }
    .projectObj .name {
      font-size:3em;
    }
    .paddRow {
      padding-bottom:30px;
    }
    .paddRow .head {
      font-size:3em;
      margin:30px 0;
    }
    .paddRow .close {
      right:20px;
      top:60px;
      width:30px;
    }
    .projectHead .picture {
      width:67%;
    }
    .projectHead .picture.right {
      margin-right:16.5%;
    }
    .projectHead .text {
      position:static;
      width:100%;
    }
    .projectHead .centerText {
      width:70%;
    }
    .view-enter,.view-leave {
      -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
      transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
      font-size:70%;
      margin:0;
    }
    header {
      height:50px;
    }
    header .logo {
      display:none;
    }
    header nav {
      margin-top:3px;
    }
    header nav ul li {
      margin-right:3px;
    }
    header nav ul li a {
      border-radius:20px;
      font-size:1.3em;
      padding:5px 14px;
    }
    .wrap {
      padding:0 10px;
    }
    .paddRow {
      padding-bottom:20px;
    }
    .paddRow .head {
      margin:20px 0;
    }
    .paddRow .close {
      right:10px;
      top:45px;
      width:20px;
    }
    .about .image {
      margin:10% auto;
      width:60%;
    }
    .about .abIcon {
      display:inline;
    }
    .projectHead .centerText {
      width:90%;
    }
    .about .txt,.input {
      width:100%;
    }
    .about .flLeft,.about .flRight,.input.email {
      float:none;
    }
}
* { margin: 0;
}
html, body { height: 100%;
}
.wrapper { min-height: 100%; height: auto !important; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer, .push { height: 4em;
}
ul.a {
    list-style-type: circle;
}









* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'zocial', sans-serif;
}
/*[data-icon]:before {
    font-family: 'zocial';
    content: attr(data-icon);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}*/
body {
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;

    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition:  all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}






footer {
 /* background-color: #212121;*/
}
/*#footer{

background-image: img src="img/footback.png";
  /*position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}*/




contact {

   background-color: ;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}
contact > ul li .text {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-left: 105px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
}





/*-----------------------------------------------------------------Footer styles------------------------------------*/


footer .splitter {
   /* background-color: #ac0;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.25, transparent),
        color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)),
        color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, transparent),
        to(transparent));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%,
        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%,
        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%,
        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%,
        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%,
        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
        transparent 75%, transparent);
*/
    -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
    -moz-background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-color: #450045;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px gray;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px gray;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px gray;

    height: 10px;
}






/*footer > ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin top: 10px auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 25px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
}*/
footer > ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    width: 33.3%;

    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
footer > ul li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}
footer > ul li:nth-child(3) {
    padding-right: 0;
}
footer > ul li .icon {
    color: #999999;
    float: left;
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
}
footer > ul li .text {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-left: 105px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
}
.text h4 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}




.text h5 {
    color: #6c6c6c;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text a {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted transparent;
    color: #FFDD00;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.text a:hover {
    border-color: #FFDD00;
}



/*footer .bar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
footer .bar-wrap {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
}*/
.links {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    position: relative;
}
.links li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.links a {
    color: #778888;
}
.links a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.clearFinance {
    color: #2D3739;
    margin-top: 5px;
}




@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
    .links, .social, .copyright{
        float:none;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .links li {
        display:inline-block;
        float:none;
    }
    .bar {
        position:relative;
    }
    .bar-wrap {
        margin-bottom:0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 835px)  {
    footer > ul li {
        float:none;
        width:auto;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px)  {
    .links li {
        margin-right:5px;
    }
}


div[back-img]{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    color: #fff;
}


div[back-img2]{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    color: #fff;
}


/*div[back-img3]{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
}*/

#back-Img3{
   /* width: 100%;*/
    height:1000px;
    background-image:url(/img/chester.png);
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;

  background-position:bottom center;
}

/*footer end-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/



/*form----------------------------------------------*/


.form-wrapper{

    width: 70%;
    height: 90%;
     margin: 50px auto;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    color: #bfbfbf;
}



 .form-wrapperTitle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35%;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #fff;
    border: #2d2d2d solid 1px;

    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-image:url('/img/oilandgas.png');
}


 .form-wrapperBack {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;

   background-image: url("/img/river.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-height: 100%;
}


.full-background {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("/img/river.png");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}







/* .form-wrapperFooter {
    width: 70%;
    height: 15%;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #fff;
    border: #2d2d2d solid 1px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}*/

.form-fundBackground {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
     box-shadow: 0px 9px 24px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.form-wrapperRight{

    width: 40%;
    height: 90%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 580px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius:;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    color: #bfbfbf;
}











ul# .active{
    border-color: white;
    border-left-color: black;
    border-top-color: black;
    color: white;
    background-color: #adadad;
}


#ex1Slider .slider-selection {
        background: #BABABA;
}






























/* colorDissolve  */
.colorDissolve {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  background: #000000;
}
.colorDissolve .item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: colorDissolve 24s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: colorDissolve 24s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: colorDissolve 24s linear infinite;
  animation: colorDissolve 24s linear infinite;
}
.colorDissolve .item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.colorDissolve .item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
span2{
position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:20px;
    color:#000000;
     font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif;  font-size:30.0px; line-height:1.19em
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}

span3{
position:absolute;
    top:85px;
    left:110px;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif;  font-size:30.0px; line-height:1.19em;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}





.colorDissolve .item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorDissolve {
    0%, 25%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
    4.17%, 20.84% { opacity: 1;}
}
@-moz-keyframes colorDissolve {
    0%, 25%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
    4.17%, 20.84% { opacity: 1;}
}
@-ms-keyframes colorDissolve {
    0%, 25%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
    4.17%, 20.84% { opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes colorDissolve {
    0%, 25%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
    4.17%, 20.84% { opacity: 1;}
}


















.slide {
  position:relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.slide.ng-enter,
.slide.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.slide.ng-enter {
    left: 100%;
}
.slide.ng-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}
.slide.ng-leave {
    left: 0;
}
.slide.ng-leave-active {
    left: -100%;
}
```

This is part of index.html.  I've followed people's advice on here and changed the mark up...but still the colour won't change?

```
<body>



  <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
  <header>





    <div class="wrap">
      <!-- logo -->

       <a href="#!"><img class="logo" src="img/history_00.png" /></a>
  <h7>Building lasting relationships<h7>



<ng-controller = "demoCtrl">

<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">



      <li ng-class="{active: isState('home') }">
        <a ui-sref="home">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{active: isState('form') }">
        <a ui-sref="form">CANDIDATES</a>
      </li>
       <li ng-class="{active: isState('clients') }">
        <a ui-sref="clients">CLIENTS</a>
      </li>
       <li ng-class="{active: isState('aboutus') }">
       <a ui-sref="aboutus">ABOUT US</a>
      </li>

      <li ng-class="{active: isState('training') }">
        <a ui-sref="training">TRAINING</a>
      </li>


    </ul>
    <h3 class="text-muted">          </h3>
    <br>
</div>

</header>
```

Comment: can you provide a demo/link that shows the problem you're having so that we can inspect/debug it?

Comment: Don't know much about angularjs but I believe your markup is a bit messed up. You have a `<header>` tag between the `<head>` tag and the `<body>` tag. It should be inside the `<body>` tag. You are referencing an `<h7>`. There are **2** closing DIV tags without an opening DIV tag which I think one was meant for your `ng-controller` element. This may or may not affect your CSS but will likely become problematic later.

Comment: This is only part of my website.  I'm only showing the navbar part hence the closing div tags.

Comment: inspect the rules that apply within browser console css inspector...write rules that are more selector specific

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0rrwvkkn/

Comment: We get that it's a part of your website but things like an `h7` and a `header` tag between the `head` and `body` tag do not compute. I'm not buying your closing DIV argument, there's a closing DIV tag in the middle of your `li` list. @charlietfl is most likely right, your issue probably has to do with specificity.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments to your question you have some incorrect markup. As I am not familiar with angularjs I have no clue if it is moving elements around once fully loaded but I'm going to guess that it doesn't.

That being said, you have CSS selectors like these:

- `header nav`
- `header nav ul`
- `header nav ul li`
- `header nav ul li a`
- `header nav ul li a.active`
- `header nav ul li a.active:hover`
- `header nav ul li a:hover, header nav ul li a.activeSmall`

I believe these are what you're trying to style your navigation with.

The problem is, based on the HTML you have supplied, that the CSS selectors listed above will not select anything. Let's look at the `header nav ul` rule. This rule says:

> Select any `ul` element that is a descendant of any `nav` element that is a descendant of any `header` element.

You do not have a `<nav>` element in your HTML and the CSS selector will fail because it cannot match anything.

You do however have a class of `.nav` in your markup. So modify your selector from:

`header nav ul` to `header .nav ul`

*Though I'm sure you're aware of this, a CSS class selector begins with a period.

Unfortunately this will not work either as it doesn't match your markup. If your unordered list with the class of `.nav` was actually contained within your `<header>` tag you'd be on the right track. But `.nav` is also the `ul` you want to target so `header .nav ul` won't work either. With that selector you'd be targeting a any `ul` that's a descendant of any `.nav` that is a descendant of any header. Simplify it to `header .nav` or `header ul`.

Currently your markup goes a little something like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta>
        <link>
    <header>
        <div>
    <body>
        <ng-controller> <!-- supposed to be a div? -->
        <ul>
           <li> <!-- random closing div tag inside one of these li -->
               <a>
        <h3>
```

For your selectors to work you need to make the modification mentioned above to target a class of nav and not a nav element and then you need to adjust your markup. Move the `<header>` tag out from between the `<head>` and `<body>` tags and into the `<body>` tag.

Something along these lines (not complete answers, will need to be adjusted for your markup):

**CSS**

```css
header .nav {
     /* your styles here */
}
header .nav li {
     /* your styles here */
}
header .nav li a {
     /* your styles here */
}
/* ... etc. ... */
```

**HTML**

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <ul class="nav">
           <li><a></a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</body>
```

Oh, and one more thing, make sure your CSS selectors are as specific or more specific that those of Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. I've taken on board what you've said and changed the markup. However the colour still won't change.

Also changed the css to what you said.

Comment: Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Actually I missed one thing, `.nav` is your `ul` so you wouldn't want both in the CSS selector as `header .nav ul`. Since `.nav` is the `ul` we want to target it should/could simply be `header .nav`. See this updated jsFiddle you provided in the comments, http://jsfiddle.net/0rrwvkkn/1/. I have simplified the fiddles HTML and CSS. Though I fixed them in the fiddle you have numerous errors in your CSS - see your original `header nav ul li a` rule (extra closing bracket, extra #, no value for border-radius). I have updated my answer.